# Find longest vector of fully compatible unique values

Tags: algorithm

I have a compatibility matrix, where 0 means that two elements are compatible, 1 means they are not.

I need to find the longest possible vector of unique elements such that all elements are compatible with each other.

Here is the matrix

[image]

I can find many empirical ways to start and see how far I can go, but is there a mathematically sound algorithms that ensures me to find the longest possible vector?

Just to be clear, I'm looking at something like:

v = [A, B, F, I...]

where all elements are compatible with each other.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: Bron--Kerbosch specifically could handle this easily, not sure what tooling you're using.

Comment: thank you very much, both comments were very useful!
I am using R and ended up using the igraph package and the longest_clicques function, 3 lines of code!